# Why sort the points acc to y coordinates in closest point divide and conquer method?

Tags: algorithms, geometry

The divide and conquer strategy for closest point problem sorts the points according to x coordinates so that the median could be found. But what does sorting the strip (strip array contains all the points which are at most d perpendicular distance apart from the median line where d is the minimum distance till now) according to the y coordinates serve any purpose? Is there something that cannot be done by the already x coordinate sorted array?

[Link for reference](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Ecs251/ClosestPair/ClosestPairDQ.html#anal)

Comment: Look at 3.2: *Thankfully, we can make another life saving observation at this point...*

Comment: The link works in my device.

Comment: @user12208242 you did nothing wrong with your URL. I'm seeing that Safari on Mac is Ok with the tilde "~" character as is, but somehow fails when it is properly re-encoded as "%7E". I tested this separately on a page on my Mac. But the current edit and your original seemed to work fine on Chrome from Windows. Also on Safari, a forward slash oddly shows up after ".html" before the anchor ".html/#anal" and that fails. So there are two things here that Safari on my Mac dislikes. I put in an edit that Safari seemed OK with but there's another edit instead that still fails for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in the previous section 3.2 I've quoted below. I think this answers your immediate question.

> However, since we sorted the points in the strip by their
> y-coordinates the process of merging our two subsets is not linear,
> but in fact takes O(nlogn) time.